# How do I link to a manpage on ubuntu.com without specifying an Ubuntu release?

Tags: manpage, ubuntu-website

Ubuntu has a website providing the manual pages ("manpage") shipped with Ubuntu packages. For example, here are the manpages for rsync:

| Ubuntu version | Link to rsync manpage |
| --- | --- |
| Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic) | https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/rsync.1.html |
| Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal) | https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/rsync.1.html |
| Ubuntu 21.10 (Impish) | https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/en/man1/rsync.1.html |
| Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy) | https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/rsync.1.html |
| Ubuntu 22.10 (Kinetic) | https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/en/man1/rsync.1.html |

I would like to create a link to rsync's manpage hosted on Ubuntu.com that automatically redirects to the latest released version of Ubuntu, something like this (notice the `stable` word):

https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/stable/en/man1/rsync.1.html

If I click on that example link, it redirects me to the latest unreleased version of Ubuntu (at the time of writing Ubuntu 22.10), instead of the latest released version of Ubuntu (at the time of writing Ubuntu 22.04 LTS). How do I create a link to the latest released version?

Comment: First, I guess you need to decide how to find out which release is the latest. You could scrape the [Releases Wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases), to find the latest current release, and substitute the string this way. I'm not sure if there is a better way.

Comment: @ArturMeinild I was wondering whether manpages.ubuntu.com supports this with a specific keyword that I wasn't aware of.

Comment: Yeah I don't know that..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The script that's used for this redirection](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-manpage-repository-dev/ubuntu-manpage-repository/production/view/head:/cgi-bin/search.py) is not very complex. It just picks the last link from a list it generated based on Ubuntu releases and manpage sections and sends you there:

```py
if matches > 0:
    if "titles" in get and get["titles"].value == "404":
        # If we were sent here by a 404-not-found, and we have at least one
        # match, redirect the user to the last page in our list
        html += "<script>location.replace('" + href_path + "');</script>"
    else:
        # Otherwise, a normal title search, display the title table
        html += title_html
else:
    # But if we do not find any matching titles, do a full text search
    html += ("</div></div><section class='p-strip u-no-padding--top'>"
             "<div class='row'><strong>No matching titles found - "
             "Full text search results below</strong>")
```

As can be seen elsewhere in the code, it just has a mapping from release code names (e.g., `jammy`) to full versions (`22.04 LTS`). No keywords like `stable` or `latest` or anything else is mentioned anywhere.

So, no, this isn't possible with the current system.